# Change the NAVBAR colour for bootstrap framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the blue colour of my `navbar` header. Unfortunately, could not find colour code in my newly created bootstrap code.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="ja/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/proper.js"></script>
    <title>Python Buddha</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div id = "Header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><h3>Python Buddha</h3></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Me</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CV</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Volunteering</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: please check updated code below and vote up ☺

Comment: voted up. thanks. for my question also please !

Comment: ty....keep it up...☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your solution with blue Navbar**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'); /* remove this link u already given this link in ur html code */

.navbar-dark{
  background-color: blue !important; /* your navbar color blue */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="ja/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/proper.js"></script>
    <title>Python Buddha</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div id = "Header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><h3>Python Buddha</h3></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Me</a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CV</a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Volunteering</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </div>
```

If you want then you can edit this file 
 [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6rdqn54x/)

This is color code link [color code link](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/)

Comment: may I ask please why the `<h3>Python Buddha</h3> ` is showing me blue coloured?

Comment: which color you want ? because you wrote classs instead of class

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is specify the `background-color` as inline css (no need to use `!important`). See bootstrap [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/?#color-schemes)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

Comment: may I ask please why the `<h3>Python Buddha</h3> ` is showing me blue coloured?

Comment: Have a look at the style applied to your `h3`. Don’t know if that can help but I just observed a typo in the parent ˋaˋ tag (`class` instead of ˋclass`) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Inline CSS in HTML**:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: red !important">
```

OR

add a custom CSS class in HTML and in CSS override that will `!important`

[codepen working demo](https://codepen.io/nitinnairdev/pen/orEZed)

Comment: may I ask please why the `<h3>Python Buddha</h3> ` is showing me blue coloured?

Comment: check the color of the `<h3>` tag you have added in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You could use SASS and in your **custom sass file**, overwrite the default color scheme of Bootstrap:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #006699,
  "danger": #cc0000
);
```

And so on.

You can use Gulp to compile SASS into CSS. In a file called gulpfile.js you should have something like:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });


    // Static Server + watching scss/html files
    gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./build"  
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'], ['js']);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['js','serve']);
```

Comment: may I ask please why the `<h3>Python Buddha</h3> ` is showing me blue coloured?